# getting soundcloud authorization code in django

Tags: django, soundcloud

I'm attempting to have soundcloud authorize my django app, which i have successfully registered with soundcloud. I pass in the details supplied during registration as well as the callback uri (http://localhost:8000/profile/).

I call the login page, which prompts me to allow my app to access my soundcloud account. I accept.

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        client = soundcloud.Client(
            client_id=settings.CLIENT_ID, 
            client_secret=settings.CLIENT_SECRET,
            redirect_uri=settings.REDIRECT_URI,
            )

        return HttpResponseRedirect(client.authorize_url())
    return render(request, 'login.html', {})
```

Soundcloud provides my callback link with the authorization_code appended.

```
http://localhost:8000/profile/?code=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...etc...&signed_up=0
```

To extract the code in order to get the exchange token, I do this:

```
    urlpatterns = patterns('core.views',

    url(r'^login/$', 'login', name='login'),
    (r'^profile/\?code=(?P<code>[\d\w]{32}).*/$', 'profile'),


    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

but get a 'page not found'. What am I doing wrong here?? I have checked the regex in shell and it returns the code...

I'm new to oAuth and api's so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your URL Pattern look like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('core.views',
    url(r'^login/$', 'login', name='login'),
    url(r'^profile/$', 'profile'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

In your profile view, you can get `code` from query string like this:

```
def profile(request):
    code = request.GET.get("code", None)
    if not code:
        ## code has not been set in query string
        ## do something

    ## do something with code you have
```

Easy and Simple !!